# Solr: Determine if an arbitrary string contains specifict text

Tags: solr

I'm trying to solve this problem using Solr:

In a dedicated core I have loaded some specific pieces of text, defined in schema.xml like this:

```
...
<field name="pieceOfText" type="text_general" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
...
```

These are examples of pieceOfText:
"this is some text"
"this is text"
"this is other text"

Now, given any arbitrary querystring, such as "this is some text in an arbitrary string", i want Solr to return me ONLY the pieceOfText
which matches at 100% with a contiugous part of the querystring. For the example above, it would return "this is some text" only, while "this is text" and "this is other text" should not appear in the results, because they don't 100% math with respet to the querystring.

I've tried mm="100%" but it seems it doesn' work for me since it forces edismax to find a pieceOfText which matches with respect to the 100% of the querystring, (right?)

I defined this reqestHandler:

```
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="df">pieceOfText</str>
       <int name="qs">0</int>
       <str name="fl">pieceOfText,score</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Any suggestion would be very appreciated!
Thanks all
Stefano

Comment: Have you tried with phrase boosting (pf,pf2 and pf3)? This will give an additional boost to your results where the phrase is found and ideally should be able to push a contiguous match to the top.

Comment: Thanks Binoy, useful tip, seems better now, the problem now is how to identify let me say "false positive" matches, nevertheless is a step forward!

Comment: Also, for your particular use case, I think you will benefit by using the ShingleFilterFactory during both index and query time without stemming and any other character based operations.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a phrase search is used to find a small phrase (query) in long texts (unit of retrieval /UoR). In your case the UoR is a small phrase and your query is a long text.

This is a hard problem for an inverted index.

1. You could write your own query parser (use `SpanPositionCheckQuery` as starting point) or ...
2. You could expand your query to a lot of phrases like a n-gram search:

   - add a token `<start>` as first token of all your UoR and a token `<end>` as last token.
   - instead for the query "A B C" search with this OR-clauses:

     1. "`<start>` A `<end>`"
     2. "`<start>` B `<end>`"
     3. "`<start>` C `<end>`"
     4. "`<start>` A B `<end>`"
     5. "`<start>` B C `<end>`"
     6. "`<start>` A B C `<end>`"
3. do not tokenize your UoR ([KeywordTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/KeywordTokenizer.html)) and use [ShingleFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html) for the query.

Comment: Thanks Karsten, for the time being I'm trying to end up with a solution which does not require coding, if it will prove not good enough I'll definitely end up witha custom query parser. Thanks again!